# How a modem really works?

Tags: ethernet, network-interface, modem

I really searched a lot and couldn't find a detailed answer(s), what happens when the Network Interface Card sends a Ethernet frame to the modem? Does the frame directly go inside modem's cpu or ethernet interface send this frame to modem's ram and raise an interrupt? What is the role of cpu in modem? Where the Ethernet interface is located?

I know lots of questions but i really obsessed with hardware internals.

Comment: Single electronic design questions are required.

Comment: You'll need to pay more attention to your question, as it is it makes no sense to me. which 'the Network Interface Card' and which 'modem'? Ethernet frames are generaly not send using a modem. How exactly a PC CPU communicates with a card depends on that cards interface (PCI?) and the (hardware and software) design choices the card manufacturer made.

Comment: Hi Wouter, let me make it clear; suppose that u want to send data to tcp server, operating system's network stack recognize this data and if this data is larger than the Ethernet MTU, it splits this data to frames(Ethernet Frames) and than operating system pass these frames one by one to Network Interface Card, if u are in home network(small network), ur computer's NIC will send these ethernet frame to modem with Ethernet protocol,right? My point is how modem welcomes these packets?

Comment: Op likely means modem in the general way, cable or fios or dsl modem.

Comment: @spartacus: In the case you describe (some form of UTP network) there is no modem: the data is not modulated (modem means: mudulator / demodulator). It is sent in 'baseband' way: just as it is, probably with some encoding, which is done inside the NI.

Comment: @ Wouter van Ooijen u are still not understanding me, of course i know one of the components of modem is modulator and demodulator another one but also there is a cpu in a "dsl modem" right?  u say; "there is no modem"??? so where the ethernet frames go from nic??? computer-modem-phone line this is the order, why u are still saying that there is no modem?this is a modem => http://www.yollasepete.com/urun/Airties-Rt205-Kablosuz-Modem_u09.jpg :)

Comment: @Wouter van Ooijen: apart from most DSL modems not being a traditional modem (e.g. 56k dialup) isn't the DSL signal modultated with DMT and OFDM which keeps these devices into the category of modems?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A modem, in general terms, has three parts. The first is modem part, changing one signal to another, like dialup modulating and demodulating analog signals, a cable modem demodulating rf frequency or a fios modem changing fiber optic signals into a locally usable form. The second is a router, and the third an Ethernet switch (even if single port).

When a computer sends a packet, it hits the switch. An Ethernet co-processor analyzes the packet, and if on the same network, sends it back out the correct port. It often doesn't even interact with the main cpu. If on a different network, it gets sent up to the routing processor, mainly the cpu of the device. If there is a route to that intended network it forwards it. If that means out through the modem part, then the cpu encapsulates the Ethernet packet into the communication method used for the connection, then encodes it into the physical layer of the network and sends it out, at which point the other end unpacks it, analyses where it should go based on the packet headers,  and repack if needed to send out again.

Read this much more accurate and detailed E.E. times article on how Cable Modems work. Trust me, if you really want to know this is gold. http://www.eetimes.com/document.asp?doc_id=1255090

Comment: this is what i want,thanks god for sending clever people :)

Comment: -1 You're totally ignoring GSM modems, Bluetooth modems, Wi-Fi modems, and telephone modems -- they all do.  A Wi-Fi router combines a Wi-Fi modem with an Ethernet router.  A standalone router, which accepts a Ethernet cable and has several Ethernet ports, is *not* a modem.  Once again your emphasis on Ethernet details is relevant to has nothing to do with GSM, Bluetooth, or telephone modems.

Comment: Considering op was specifying consumer isp modems via Ethernet... @tcrosley and I never talked about stand-alone routers or wifi...

Comment: @Passerby The title of the question is: *"How a modem really works?"*  Modems don't care anything about the Ethernet or packets, they just transmit bits.  Given the OP seems confused about this, and brings up Ethernet, doesn't mean Ethernet and packets need to be discussed.  It's just adding confusion.

Comment: op said that was "exactly what I want". He wanted an explication on how a typical dsl/cable/fios to Ethernet works. @tcrosley

Comment: @tcrosley: You're stuck in the past. Voice-band modems are an ancient relic. Nowadays, when your ISP sends you a "modem" -- whether it's for DSL, cable TV or optical fiber -- it most definitely interfaces via Ethernet.

Comment: @DaveTweed  The OP asked how a modem works.  I thought it was relevant to provide some history.  I did include DSL modems in my answer, and indicated they were Ethernet based.

Comment: @tcrosley: Maybe, but all of that is tangential to the question, as indicated by the OP. Your negative comments (and vote) on this answer are inappropriate.

Comment: ok, I'll delete my answer.  Hope you're happy now.

Comment: @tcrosley: No, your answer is OK. I was referring specifically to your negative  comments and your downvote of *this* (Passerby's) answer.